# Start/stop self-hosted WCF data service programmatically

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf-data-services

HI I have a solution with a couple of projects.
One of them is a self-hosted WCF Data service.

This service is running fine on his own, but I want to start it from my main method.
This way I can control wether is should start or stop.

Why I need to do this is that I can run my main method and let the service start, but when the program exits, the service is still running.

Anybody know how to fix my problem?

--EDIT--

This service thing is new to me. So I'm not even sure it's possible.
Let's say I have 2 projects. One contains my main method and the other is a WCF Service Application project.
I want to be able to stop my service from within the main project whenever I want to.

--EDIT2--

I am creating a system that can provide data to clients through an API (WCF Data services). When my system starts, I want to start the service. When my system shuts down, my service have to stop existing or at least providing data.

Comment: Maybe you can give some more information on your scenario. If you really want to start the service when your application is running and stop it as soon as your application ends, then having a dedicated service in the first place doesn't make any sense. You could at well use the service class as a normal instance variable in your application.

Comment: Can you post the hosting-part of the code of your self hosted service? Can't you just use this code in your application to host your service? Normally you should have a ServiceHost that has Open() and Close() methods. You just need to call Close(). If it's two seperate applications (Application & Service) maybe it would be a good idea to have only one common application doing both, whatever you application does, plus service hosting.